# How do you perform an upsert using Couchbase?

Tags: node.js, couchbase

I am looking for similar functionality as MongoDB's upsert in Couchbase. An answer for Node.js using the Couchbase module is preferable.

Comment: MongoDB works differently than Couchbase, in particular the way documents are written and updated. What are you trying to do specifically where you think you'd need it?

Comment: Upserting is convenient in situations where data with an id is being provided from an external source and you want to store a new resource as well as the most recent version of a resource. I don't believe debating the merits of upserting is necessary to answering this question though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It will be better if you add more information about what do you want to do. In general MongoDB's `upsert` analogue in Couchbase is [set](http://www.couchbase.com/autodocs/couchbase-node-client-1.1.1/Connection.html#set) operation. It will write data with given key into db. If there was such key in db, it will overwrite it. If there was no such key, it will create it.

But may be you can have some cases, where you probably will need other functions like: [add](http://www.couchbase.com/autodocs/couchbase-node-client-1.1.1/Connection.html#add), [replace](http://www.couchbase.com/autodocs/couchbase-node-client-1.1.1/Connection.html#replace), [incr](http://www.couchbase.com/autodocs/couchbase-node-client-1.1.1/Connection.html#incr), [decr](http://www.couchbase.com/autodocs/couchbase-node-client-1.1.1/Connection.html#decr).

Comment: Worth nothing that Couchbase and CouchDB currently do not support partial update upserts like MongoDB.

Comment: As far as I know this feature is planned for future release (at least developers have it in issue list). In most my cases when I used couchbase there were no big need to update parts of docs (all my data were divided in small docs, so updating whole doc has not very big overhead). May be in your situation you can also rethink your data model. Also some examples of your docs and operations you want to perform will be very useful. Your question is too general, try to concretize it, if you wnat to get more helpful answers.